# How to write custom formatting rules for clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there any documentation on customizing the behavior of `clang-format` itself? My Google-fu is failing me. I would like to write some small additional (simple) formatting rules. It seems this is not possible in a simple way, except for patching [`LibFormat`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibFormat.html) itself which I hope to avoid.

Is there anyone with some experience in this matter? What would be the best approach? Is there some prior art here?

Comment: I think it's not possible without patching LibFormat. Also see the links at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207030/how-to-add-capabilities-to-clang-format/63444726#63444726

Comment: @EricBackus, thank you for the pointer.