# How to add capabilities to clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

Clang is good for keeping everyone honest regarding the company's coding standards, but it does not provide complete coverage of all cases and makes (IMO) bad choices instead of ignoring certain situations. For example (from another post with similar concerns):

```
z1 = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

gets "mangled" by clang-format into

```
z2 = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

Sure that follows the company standards, but the z1 expression is easier to recognize at a glance. I want clang-format to *ignore* (not add nor remove) spaces around binary operators. I don't see *any* setting for spaces around binary operators for that matter. It just does it whether I want it or not.

So, can I add the capability to handle a new parameter like
`SpaceAroundBinaryOperator: true|false|ignore`?
I.e., is the clang-format code accessible to an experienced C++ programmer without having to spend a week or more just figuring out the code? Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, can I add the capability to handle a new parameter...

> is the clang-format code accessible to an experienced C++ programmer without having to spend a week or more just figuring out the code?

There is this: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#adding-additional-style-options, but there isn't much information there.

Also this: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibFormat.html

And maybe this: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/#design-documents

But I think you really would have to dive into the [source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project). There's a lot of code (since `clang-format` code is part of the whole clang C++ compiler and related tools LLVM project), so I think you'll want a week or more to figure things out. Just my guess though...